# Performing a query on a foreign table but returning only the original table?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a Item and Person table, where the Person 'id' column matches the Item 'person_id' column. I want to retrieve records in the Item table where the owner (Person) of the Item has 'category' 1. Sample structure below:

| Item |
| --- |
| id |
| item_name |
| person_id |

| Person |
| --- |
| id |
| name |
| category (can be 1, 2, or 3) |

I understand that I can use 'join' to find rows of the Item table where the two ids match, but I cannot use join for my use case. I need my SQL query to return only Item columns, and *not* Person columns. Basically, how can I construct a query that will query a table using values in another table, while still maintaining the original table structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that I can use 'join' to find rows of the Item table where the two ids match, but I cannot use join for my use case. I need my SQL query to return only Item columns, and not Person columns.

This statement is just false.  You can select whatever columns you want when joining:

```
select i.*
from items i join
     persons p
     on i.person_id = p.id and p.category = 1;
```

In terms of constructing the query, `exists` is also a very reasonable approach, but you can definitely use `join`.

Answer (score 2):

One way is using EXISTS with correlated subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM Item i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Person p
              WHERE p.id = i.person_id AND p.category = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use IN clause to filter the person table with category 1

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE person_id IN ( 
    SELECT Id FROM Person WHERE category=1)
```

Comment: There is no need to use `DISTINCT` here. Id of Person is unique and even if it was not, the `IN` would work the same way even on duplicate values.